# Ordinal regression model in brms; Error =the function cumulative("logit") could not be found

Tags: r, ordinal, brms

I'm trying to run the ordinal logit model with the brms package, and I got the error "The function "cumulative" could not be found. I changed it to family = "cumulative" and was able to get it to work. Are these different?

```
 bmodel<- brms::brm(pop ~  RDB2000pop + Temperature2003 + Population2003 +  
                              (1+RDB2000pop+Temperature2003+Population2003|species_id),
                 data      = dfpop_chenv,
                 family    = cumulative(link = "logit", threshold = "flexible"),
                 warmup    = 100,
                 iter      = 500,
                 chains    = 4,
                 cores     = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because you are calling the function `brm()` through specifying `brms::brm()`. This means that the other functions included with the package like `cumulative()` have not been loaded.

I made some toy ordinal data from the mtcars package to reproduce the error with the following code:

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.ordered(mtcars$cyl)
```

I then get the same error if I try and fit a model with code similar to yours:

```
m1 <- brms::brm(cyl ~ mpg,
          data = mtcars,
          family = cumulative(link = "logit", threshold = "flexible"))

Error in cumulative(link = "logit", threshold = "flexible") : 
  could not find function "cumulative"
```

However, if instead, I load the package using `library()`, I can call code similar to yours and the model fits with no problems. This is because the family functions available from Stan though *brms* are often not available in base R.

```
library(brms)
m1 <- brm(cyl ~ mpg,
          data = mtcars,
          family = cumulative(link = "logit", threshold = "flexible"))
```

Now the model doesn't make too much sense here, but it fits without issues.

```
summary(m1)
 Family: cumulative 
  Links: mu = logit; disc = identity 
Formula: cyl ~ mpg 
   Data: mtcars (Number of observations: 32) 
Samples: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup samples = 4000

Population-Level Effects: 
             Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept[1]   -39.51     13.40   -72.37   -19.61 1.01      775      821
Intercept[2]   -34.24     11.83   -63.63   -16.48 1.01      827      863
mpg             -1.85      0.63    -3.42    -0.91 1.01      803      884

Family Specific Parameters: 
     Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
disc     1.00      0.00     1.00     1.00 1.00     4000     4000

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The model on my data fit without issues!